# Reading a column with HTML address

Tags: functions

I have a csv file or an excei that looks as below:

[image: csv file with columns - path]

I would like to first import the first cell with the hyperlink (in blue) and extract everything and put the output into the column next to column "path"

I have the following codes so far: (first line importing the column with hyperlinks)

```
data1 = dataset[1, All, 6];

data2 = data1[3]; <-this line is referring to the third row

data3 = StringSplit[Import[data2, "Plaintext"], ","];

data4 = StringReplace[#, (StartOfString ~~ ",") | ("," ~~ 
         EndOfString) :> ""] & /@ data3;
data5 = StringReplace[#, (StartOfString ~~ Whitespace) | (Whitespace ~~
          EndOfString) :> ""] & /@ data4;
data6 = StringSplit[ToString[data5], " "];
data7 = StringSplit[data6, ".htm "];
```

I have the output:

```
{{"Description"}, {"Document"}, {"Type"}, {"Size
  "}, {"1"}, {"PROXY"}, {"2010"}, {"proxy2010.htm"}, {"DEF"}, \
{"14A"}, {"717341
  "}}
```

I just need to take the part where it says "xxx.htm" <- with xxx constantly changing for every row, but it should always have ".htm" at the end.

My question is

1. From the output above, can I take the ".htm" part of the output and store the .htm address to a variable?
2. Can I run this entire process from rows 2 through 100?

Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean by "extract everything"?

Comment: I edited my post - hopefully, this is more clear. Thank you both for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have the imported data in an array with rows similar to:

```
row={{"Description"}, {"Document"}, {"Type"}, {"Size"}, {"1"}, {"PROXY"}, {"2010"}, {"proxy2010.htm"}, {"DEF"}, \
{"14A"}, {"717341"}}
```

To get the part you want you can use:

```
StringCases[#[[8, 1]], RegularExpression["\\d+\\.htm"]] &[row]
```

If all of your data have form:data= {row1,row2,..,row100} you may get all the relevant info at once by:

```
StringCases[#[[8, 1]], RegularExpression["\\d+\\.htm"]] & /@ data
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! May I also ask how to automate this process for 100 rows? For example, data2 above is referring to the third row based on the code "data2 = data[3]". I would like to conduct the operations above by changing the number inside data[#] such that the program takes the numbers from 2 to 100 and replace the # and run the operations above. Is there a loop function that i could utilize?

Comment: For example, i am trying the code below: For[i = 2, 
 i < 10, 
 i++,
 gethtm[x_] = data[i];
  data2 = gethtm[i];
  // Print
 ]

Comment: Loops are seldom used in MMA and they are inefficient. If you want to apply a function that does some work on data in a list like: {data1,data2,..} you use e.g. "Map" or abbreviated: "/@". Try to understand my example from above: "StringCases[#[[8, 1]], RegularExpression["\\d+\\.htm"]] & /@ data". Here the function: " "StringCases[#[[8, 1]], RegularExpression["\\d+\\.htm"]] &" that extracts the "xxx.htm" is applied to every element data1,data2,... The result is a list containing the output of the function: {out1,out2,..}